# GCM Json Post method

Tags: android, json, notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm doing an android app for first time which uses gcm. I'm unable to push message notification to users with multicast. I have implemented for individual users though! Please suggest a way to implement HTTP POST request in JSON thinking me as a beginner.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue just with sending a HTTP POST request? If so, Google Volley is a good API for achieving this, check out

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Answer (score 0):

In the [GCM Architecture](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html),  your 'backend' (3rd-party server) sends the message to the GCM servers, then eventually they will reach the devices.

Typical code on the "backend" would look like (java):

```
    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", message).build();
    List<RegistrationRecord> records = getTheListOfDeviceIdsYouWantToReceiveTheMessage();


    for(RegistrationRecord record : records) {
        Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 5);
        if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
            log.info("Message sent to " + record.getRegId());
        } else {
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                log.warning("Registration Id " + record.getRegId() + " no longer registered with GCM, removing from datastore");
                // if the device is no longer registered with Gcm, remove it from the datastore

            }
            else {
                log.warning("Error when sending message : " + error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Without seeing your code, it would be hard to help you at this point.